# How to render AdMob banner in React Flatlist between items?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, admob

I have a React Native Flatlist that only re-renders when its data has changed.

I give it the following data (as prop):

```
const posts = [
    {
       ...post1Data
    },
    {
       ...post2Data
    },
    {
       ...post3Data
    },
    {
       ...post4Data
    },
    {
       ...post5Data
    },
]
```

And here is my FlatList renderItem:

```
const renderItem = useCallback(({ item, index }) => {
  const { id, userData, images, dimensions, text } = item;

  return (
    <View
      onLayout={(event) => {
        itemHeights.current[index] = event.nativeEvent.layout.height;
      }}
    >
      <Card
        id={id}
        cached={false}
        userData={userData}
        images={images}
        dimensions={dimensions}
        text={text}
      />
    </View>
  );
}, []);
```

How can I add an AdMob ad between the FlatList data with a probability of 5% without skiping any data in the posts array?

I have tried this:

```
const renderItem = useCallback(({ item, index }) => {
  const { id, userData, images, dimensions, text } = item;

  if (Math.random() < 0.05) return <Ad ... />

  return (
    <View
      onLayout={(event) => {
        itemHeights.current[index] = event.nativeEvent.layout.height;
      }}
    >
      <Card
        id={id}
        cached={false}
        userData={userData}
        images={images}
        dimensions={dimensions}
        text={text}
      />
    </View>
  );
}, []);
```

But this causes 2 problems:

1. Some items from data are skipped (not returned)
2. When the flatlist re-renders (because of some of its props changes) the ads might disappear (there is a chance of 95%).

Any ideas? Should I render the ads randomly in the footer of my Card component like this?

```
const Card = memo ((props) => {
    ...
    return (
       <AuthorRow ... />

       <Content ... />

       <SocialRow ... /> {/* Interaction buttons */}

       <AdRow />
    )
}, (prevProps, nextProps) => { ... });



const AdRow = memo(() => {
   return <Ad ... />
}, () => true);
```

I am not really sure about this option, it works but it could violate the admob regulations (?) (because I am adapting the ad to the layout of my card component)

I would appreciate any kind of guidance/help. Thank you.

Comment: You want show Ad Banner After Every Items 
Like Post1 Then Banner Then Post2 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if you ever found a solution to this problem, but I accomplished this by injecting "dummy" items into the data set, then wrapping the renderItem component with a component that switches based on the type of each item.

Assuming your flatlist is declared like this:

```
<FlatList data={getData()} renderItem={renderItem}/>
```

And your data set is loaded into a variable called `sourceData` that is tied to state. Let's assume one entry in your `sourceData` array looks like this. Note the 'type' field to act as a type discriminator:

```
{
  "id": "d96dce3a-6034-47b8-aa45-52b8d2fdc32f",
  "name": "Joe Smith",
  "type": "person"
}
```

Then you could declare a function like this:

```
const getData = React.useCallback(() => {
  let outData = [];
  outData.push(...sourceData);
  
  // Inject ads into array
  for (let i = 4; i < outData.length; i += 5)
  {
    outData.splice(i, 0, {type:"ad"});
  }
  return outData;
}, [sourceData]);
```

... which will inject ads into the data array between every 4th item, beginning at the 5th item. (Since we're pushing new data into the array, `i += 5` means an ad will be placed between every 4th item. And `let i = 4` means our first ad will show after the 5th item in our list)

Finally, switch between item types when you render:

```
const renderItem = ({ item }) => (
  item.type === 'ad'
  ?
  <AdComponent ...props/>
  :
  <DataComponent ...props/>
);
```

Comment: The helper method is awesome! I was doing it when parsing the items, which is a no-sense option... But moving the respective logic it to the component is awesome!

Comment: This works but how are you avoiding the large VirtualizedList error?

Comment: @Cory I've never received any VirtualizedList errors. Perhaps you could talk me through your scenario and I can try to help.